# Variable outputs only its first character out of its several characters string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array:

`$tb_src[1]`, `$tb_src[2]`, etc.

Before using this defintion, I'm also creating a non-array variable: `$tb_src` which I'm using in another part of the code.

For a reason I can't figure, if I use that definition, it makes the array to only contain the first character out of the string I'm trying to attribute it, so I get `z` instead of `zzx`

What's going on here?

```
$tb_src =  'n1a'; // I need to use this variable, in other part of code.
// the above line is causing the problem with below code.

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) { // defining the array

$tb_src[$i + 1] =  "zzx";

}

echo  $tb_src[1]; // why does it output only first letter 'z' and not 'zzx'?
```

Comment: `print_r($tb_src);` will tell you.

Comment: `$tb_src` is defined as a string, not an array.  Therefore, when you `echo  $tb_src[1]` it echoes element `[1]` of the string, which is the second `z` in your string.

Comment: I can't figure how this print helps. my loop is creating and applying the value `zzx` for each `$tb_src[$i] - 0,1,2. and that's only a simplified example.

Comment: @TimMorton it is echoing the first z, not the second one. and still I don't get the logic.

Comment: oops, I overlooked the `$i+1`.  So it is technically the first `z` in the string (`nzzz`),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant make an array from a string value. Instead, create a new variable with that string as the first value, then add new items to it. You can then assign it back if you wish.

```
<?php
// string
$tb_src =  'n1a';

// tmp array with above string as first value
$tmp = [$tb_src];

// add your items
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   $tmp[] =  "zzx";
}

/* $tmp is now
Array
(
    [0] => n1a
    [1] => zzx
    [2] => zzx
    [3] => zzx
)
*/

// echo second element zzx
echo  $tmp[1];

print_r($tmp);
```

https://3v4l.org/EEP1v

You could assign `$tmp` back into `$tb_src` if you wish.